# "not in" membership operator combined with "or" Boolean operator (Python)

Tags: python, membership

I'm faced with what might seem a trivial, but nevertheless very annoying conundrum. While checking for membership using the "not in" operator combined with Boolean "and" and "or" on a following dictionary:

```
    data = {"name": "david", "age": 27, "income": "absurd"}
```

I've found that:

```
#1 - found
if "name" not in data:
    print "not found"
else:
    print "found"

#2 - found
if "name" not in data and "income" not in data:
    print "not found"
else:
    print "found"

#3 - found
if "name" and "income" not in data:
    print "not found"
else:
    print "found"

#4 - found
if "name" not in data or "income" not in data:
    print "not found"
else:
    print "found"

#5 - NOT found (though it should be?)
if "name" or "income" not in data:
    print "not found"
else:
    print "found"
```

For my money #4 and #5 are logically identical, but clearly they can't be. I looked over the official Python reference but it only added to confusion. Could someone shed a light on this?

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times.  Hint: `"name" or "income" not in data` means `("name" or "income") not in data`.  What is the value of `"name" or "income"`?

Comment: @BrenBarn: actually, that's `("name") or ("income" not in data)`. [`or` has a lower precedence than `not in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: Why do they keep thinking that would work? `"name" or "income" not in data` is the incorrect way of writing `any(prop not in data for prop in ["name", "income"])`.

Comment: You can also convert a dict to a set (containing the dict's keys). So you can code `if set(data).intersection(properties_list): ...`  (empty set is Falsey, non-empty is Truthy) Not sure if this is better or worse than Dan D's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `not in` binds more strongly than both `and` and `or`. So #4 gets parsed as you would expect, while #5 is equal to `if ("name") or ("income" not in data):` – since non-empty strings are truthy in python, this means it always ends up in the "not found" branch.